# All-quantified type variable in (value) constructor cannot be explicitly typed as wanted

Tags: coq

I have the following GADT.

```
Inductive GADT : Type -> Type :=
| A : forall A, GADT A
| B : GADT bool.
```

And the following data type that has one constructor with an all-qualified type variable.

```
Inductive Wrap A :=
| wrap : GADT A -> Wrap A
| unwrap : forall X, GADT X -> (X -> Wrap A) -> Wrap A.
```

Then I want to define a recursive function that uses the function within `unwrap`.

```
Fail Fixpoint wrappedGADT {A} (xs: Wrap A) : option (GADT A) :=
  match xs with
  | wrap _ x => Some x
  | unwrap _ _ fx k => match fx with
                       | A _ => None
                       | B => wrappedGADT (k true)
                       end
end.
```

With this definition I get the following error message.

```
The term "true" has type "bool" while it is expected to have type "T".
```

I was assuming that when I inspect `fx` and get case `B`, the parameter `fx` has type `GADT bool`, thus, the all-quantified type variable `X` is `bool` as well. Is this assumption wrong?

Next, I tried to explicitly type `unwrap` as follows.

```
Fail Fixpoint wrappedGADT {A} (xs: Wrap A) : option (GADT A) :=
  match xs with
  | wrap _ x => Some x
  | @nwrap _ bool fx k => match fx with
                           | A _ => None
                           | B => wrappedGADT (k true)
                           end
  end.
```

With this definition I get a very weird error message.

`The term "true" has type "Datatypes.bool" while it is expected to have type "bool".`

Can anybody give any pointers to the origin of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, raw match statements in Coq aren't always very smart about the kind of reasoning you're applying here.  The "convoy pattern" (see CPDT for more information about it) is usually the answer for resolving this type of problem.  The immediate application here would look something like:

```
Fail Fixpoint wrappedGADT {A} (xs: Wrap A) {struct xs} : option (GADT A) :=
  match xs with
  | wrap _ x => Some x
  | unwrap _ _ fx k => match fx in (GADT T)
                       return ((T -> Wrap A) -> option (GADT A)) with
                       | A _ => fun k0 => None
                       | B => fun k0 => wrappedGADT (k0 true)
                       end k
end.
```

However, this runs into another issue, that Coq isn't able to verify the termination condition after passing the function through the "convoy".  It seems that to work around that, it suffices to first define the function of recursive calls on values of `k` and then convoy that instead:

```
Fixpoint wrappedGADT {A} (xs: Wrap A) {struct xs} : option (GADT A) :=
  match xs with
  | wrap _ x => Some x
  | unwrap _ _ fx k => let r := fun x => wrappedGADT (k x) in
                       match fx in (GADT T)
                       return ((T -> option (GADT A)) -> option (GADT A)) with
                       | A _ => fun _ => None
                       | B => fun r' => r' true
                       end r
end.
```

For your second code attempt, you're creating a local variable `bool` to hold the type called `X` in the `unwrap` constructor, which is then shadowing the `Datatypes.bool` definition.  In general, there's no way to match only on one specific type in the Coq kernel language (although typeclasses provide a way to simulate that, somewhat).

Comment: I did stumble upon the "convoy pattern" and tried a version similar to your first code example. Is the second version also something like a common pattern or is it more of a hack to convince the termination checker? Is there maybe another implementation that would work better here?

Comment: It's more of a hack to convince the termination checker.  Though I came up with it by thinking about `Wrap_rect` - which would be another potential way to write this (use `Wrap_rect` instead of directly defining a Fixpoint, probably with ample comments on what case is for what function).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative implementation, which constructs `wrappedGADT`'s body using tactics. It has one advantage that it doesn't require manual `return` annotations from the user. The overall structure closely resembles your original code with the `match` expression.

It is crucial to use `induction xs` as opposed to `destruct xs` here, because the `Wrap` type is recursive.

```
Fixpoint wrappedGADT' {A} (xs: Wrap A) : option (GADT A).
  induction xs as [x | ? fx k r].
  - exact (Some x).
  - destruct fx as [T | ].
    + exact None.
    + exact (r true).
Defined.
Print wrappedGADT'.
```

Here is a proof that the two implementations are extensionally equal.

```
Goal forall (A : Type) (xs : Wrap A),
    wrappedGADT xs = wrappedGADT' xs.
Proof with auto.
  intros A xs.
  induction xs...
  destruct g...
  simpl; rewrite H; destruct (w true)...
Qed.
```

---

If we look at the term generated for `wrappedGADT'` (using `Print wrappedGADT'.`), we'll be able to construct one more solution using the `Wrap_rect` induction principle generated for the `Wrap` datatype (I just removed unused variable `k` from the `match` expression in `wrappedGADT'`):

```
Definition wrappedGADT'' {A} (xs: Wrap A) : option (GADT A) :=
  Wrap_rect _
            _
            (fun t => Some t)
            (fun _ fx k r =>
               match fx in (GADT T)
               return ((T -> option (GADT A)) -> option (GADT A)) with
               | A _ => fun _ => None
               | B => fun r' => r' true
               end r)
            xs.
```

This solution can then lead to a solution a-la [Daniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41111181/2747511), if we unfold `Wrap_rect`, implemented as `Fixpoint` itself.